# How to get read data from response header in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpresponse, response-headers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

If the server is returned data in response header how I can read it. I am sending an AJAX request to a server. It does not return anything but the **Location** in response header. I want to read that location using JavaScript or jQuery....

Comment: Ajax request? Or normal page request?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both `XMLHttpRequest` and `jqXHR` (which is the object jQuery wraps around AJAX requests) have a [`getResponseHeader()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader%28%29), so in the `always()` handler (jQuery) or readyState handler (`XMLHttpRequest`), do `this.getResponseHeader('Location')`.

Bear in mind that if your server *also* sends a redirect status code (301/ 302) that redirect will be [*automatically* followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238727/how-to-prevent-ajax-requests-to-follow-redirects-using-jquery), and there's no way to access the intermediate-headers returned.

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, using `XMLHttpRequest` you can do that using [`getAllResponseHeaders()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders%28%29) method.

jQuery also allowing to call that method. See [more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).