# Read request header in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to read request header and thereafter fetch the variable value (say of example user id) in the jquery mobile + javascript code? If yes any example?

I found this article. [How to get read data from response header in jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548990/how-to-get-read-data-from-response-header-in-jquery-javascript), but not sure how it would work.

Comment: you mean response header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url:'url', //the request url
 data: {}, //any param that you want to send in the request
 success: function(data){ //'data' is the response
    alert(request.getResponseHeader());
 }
 error: function () {
    alert("failed");
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

use this :

```
getAllResponseHeaders()
```

more detail **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders%28%29)**

Or this:

```
getResponseHeader()
```

more detail **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader%28%29)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want request headers from this page you can get them via php getallheaders and display them as javascript array.

```
<script>
var headers = <?php echo json_encode(getallheaders()); ?>;
</script>
```