# jquery - get http headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, msisdn

How do you get the http headers passed on a page?  Is this achievable via javascript/jquery?
I'm looking into something like this: http://www.mulliner.org/pc.cgi

Comment: HTTP headers are sent from the browser to the server, so you do it in the server.

Comment: Yes. Please refer to: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548990/how-to-get-read-data-from-response-header-in-jquery-javascript