# How can i get this real link

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom and i am easily get the href link but this is not the actual link it's very long when i click the link it's open on new window and the long url convert into short or real link i want this link please help me how can i get this real link.

Here is the code which i get by using  Simple HTML DOM

```
<a href="/external.php?title=Camp+Massacre&amp;url=aHR0cDovL3ZpZHppLnR2L2Z3eWM4bmZreDJ3eC5odG1s&amp;domain=dmlkemkudHY=&amp;loggedin=1" onclick="return  addHit('1894159921', '1')" rel="nofollow" title="Watch Version 1 of Camp Massacre" target="_blank">Version 1</a>
```

And after click the link it will load this link on new window and i want this real link.

http://vidzi.tv/fwyc8nfkx2wx.html

Comment: As @ChunchiuChan points out, the server is redirecting & OP wants to know, presumably before submitting an HTTP request(?!) where it will redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, hope I get your meaning, especially "real link".

In your case, the url maybe originally something like http://www.aaa.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.php?id=1234567890
When you open the page, it becomes http://www.aaa.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/eee.php

This might be because the server redirects you to another page according to your original url. Since this is a server side matter, you, as a client, might be not able to know where you are redirected.

Another possible reason is that the server rewrite your url using .htaccess file. You may get more information from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) and [here](http://htaccess-guide.com/)

Regarding to the issue on login, some server reads cookies or keep session variables. You, thus, have to create cookies or session information and send together with you request, so that you can get the "real link".

---

I think that you are redirected, as mentioned.

Just assume that the base url is http://www.aaa.com
When accessing it, you see your the tag. The href contains the value `/external.php?title=Camp+Massacre&amp;url=aHR0cDovL3ZpZHppLnR2L2Z3eWM4bmZreDJ3eC5odG1s&amp;domain=dmlkemkudHY=&amp;loggedin=1`
You then combine the base url and the href. This, however, cannot give you `http://vidzi.tv/fwyc8nfkx2wx.html` because you are accessing a php and the server side php program redirects you to the html page.

Regarding to redirecting using php, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) might be helpful for your understanding

---

Suppose that you use AJAX, please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548990/how-to-get-read-data-from-response-header-in-jquery-javascript) by Matt. He suggests the use of `getResponseHeader('Location')` and I tried using the following webpages on my wamp server

```
=====>page_1.html
<html>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <body>
        <p>This is page 1</p>
        <a href="ext.php" target="_blank">another page</a>
    </body>
</html>

=====>page_2.html
<html>
    <title>Page 2</title>
    <body>
        <p>This is page 2</p>
    </body>
</html>

=====>ext.php
<?php
header('Location: http://localhost/testing/page_2.html');
?>

=====> page_3.html
<html>
    <title>Page 3</title>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc(){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            alert("Status Text: " + xmlhttp.status + "; " + xmlhttp.statusText);
            alert(xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders());

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert("Response text: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ext.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

    <body>
        <p onclick="loadXMLDoc();">load</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is expected that clicking the text "load" in page_3.html results in accessing ext.php, and I would be redirected to page_2.html. According to Matt, if my work is correct, I can get the "Location" attribute from header.

In this case, I use firefox to test it and I can get the html content in page_2.html, but it fails if I use opera. In both cases, I cannot see "Location" attribute from response header, and I believe this would be related to how a server write response headers. That means, again, that it would be a server side matter. Good Luck!

Comment: bro this external link is a fake link behind this short url encrypted i want this short link and it will appear after clicking on link but i don't know how can i get this original short link by simple html dom

Comment: Do you mean you click on the text "Version 1", which is embedded with the a_href tag and then see a new window, which is the page you want?

Comment: yes and i want that link which is open in new window when we click on version 1

Comment: bro please visit this link and check it out https://www.primewire.ag/watch-2757658-Camp-Massacre-online-free please need your help