# Get headers on page load from node-express app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am building an app with node and express and set it up such that when the page loads, some headers are sent to the client.  How do I extract that information on the client side?  I am using JS/jQuery on the client side.  Here's the code in question-

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  models.game_session.build({
    sid: req.sessionID
  }).save().then((data) => {
    let options = {
      "root": __dirname,
      headers: {
        "x-sid": data.id
      }
    }
    res.sendFile('/index.html', options, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      }
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.send(`There was an error`);
  });
});
```

I am saving the session ID in the database then sending the index file to the client.  As you see in the options object, I want to include the session ID in the header to be sent with the index file.  How can I retrieve that info on the client side?  I'm not sure if I am going about this in the right way- appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: sorry, didn't read closely enough. It's not actually possible, and here's why:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/220233/4045156

What you are doing is fine, but you could also (once the page loads on the client side) make another request to the server and then respond with a simple JSON object. It's totally up to you though. This of course means another request, but it doesn't seem possible to avoid another request anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't an API to get the headers from you current page, you need to generate another request from you JS/Jquery to get the headers:

How to do that:

[How to get read data from response header in jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548990/how-to-get-read-data-from-response-header-in-jquery-javascript)

[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)