# get headers from get Http request in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, httprequest, angular-services

I'm making a call to an API that gets blob data.

back end sends to me also file name in header.

My actual problem is that I can't get header from the api.

Here's my **service.ts**

```
public openFile(path) {
  let url='/download/';
  let pathFile= new HttpParams().set('pathFile', path);
  return this.httpClient.get(url,{params:pathFile, responseType: 'blob' });
```

and in **component.ts** I call the service. when I try to print the `res.headers` I get undefined in console.

```
openFile(path){
  this.creditPoliciesService.openFile(path).toPromise().then (data => {
    console.log("dataaaaaa",data.headers); // undefined
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'}); 
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
    }
    else {
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
      window.open(fileURL);
    }
  });
}
```

In the dev tool admin I get informations in response header but I'm not able to find them in the response variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548990/how-to-get-read-data-from-response-header-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: [Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: Here's i'm using Angular services it's not exactly the same

Comment: what's not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pass observe key with value of ‘response’ to get the complete response

```
getData() {
 this.http.get(this.url, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {
   this.headerProperty = res.headers.get('property name here');
 });
}
```

Comment: Should I import some modules ?

Comment: I added `{ observe: 'response' }` to my request , but I don't get all the header response items that I see in the browser devtool

Comment: I have resolved my problem by getting  the information from the front end ( instead of the http request ) . but I have found this on github it may help further person https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13226