# Angular HttpClient - Get headers from response

Tags: angular, header, httpclient

I know there are many answered questions to this but none of them has worked to me.

I am trying to do the following call:

```
this.http.options("http://...", {observe: 'response'}).subscribe((data: HttpResponse<any>) => console.log(data))
```

However the headers field from that input are empty! :

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: 

"http://...", ok: true, …}
body: ""
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0)
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
[[Entries]]: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Object
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 4
url: "http:/..."
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

But if I do that same call with Postman I get the following headers!

```
Allow →PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Fri, 28 Sep 2018 21:29:22 GMT
Server →Google Frontend
X-Cloud-Trace-Context →6627df99d34998ddeadcdcf7a2b132be;o=1
```

I need to get the 'Allow' headers but I don't seem to be able to do it.

Help pls

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135330/4399281

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two problems in your question:

1. Using Angular's `HttpClient`, response headers are lazy-loaded, which means you need to attempt to `get` the value in order to actually see that it exists. e.g.:

   ```js
    const allowValue = response.headers.get('allow');
   ```
2. To allow your client-side JavaScript to access this header, you need to set a response header (server-side, of course). The following line shows the header and the value that needs to be set:

   ```
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: allow
   ```

You can read more about this on MDN: [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).