# Angular: How to get the file name of the uploaded file

Tags: angular

Following is my Response header for POSTMAN request:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file_name.docx.docx"
```

where `file_name` is the actual file name

Now, while downloading the file in Angular, I want this exact name. But instead of that, every time I download the file it picks up some random name

Following is my angular code:

```
this.http.get("url", {responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe((res) => {
  const blob = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/msword'});
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
})
```

Is there any I can get the exact name of the file which we want to download, i.e. the same name which I am getting in Postman request header

Comment: You're already subscribing to this.http.get().  Try accessing the `.headerProperty`this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135330/421195

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this below method using `observe` and see if it fixes the issue?

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get(
        'https://www.mtsac.edu/webdesign/accessible-docs/word/example03.docx',
        {
          responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
          observe: 'response' as 'body',
        }
      )
      .subscribe(async (res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        const filename = res.headers.get('filename') || 'test.docx';
        const blob = res.body;
        const blobFinal = new Blob([blob as Blob], {
          type: 'application/msword',
        });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobFinal);
        console.log(url);
        var fileLink = document.createElement('a');
        fileLink.href = url;
        fileLink.download = filename;
        fileLink.click();
      });
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-file-as-blob-dcdsjw)

Comment: res.headers.get('filename') Not working

Comment: NOTE: if I tried to hit the url directly in any browser then also file is getting downloaded with proper name

Comment: @SafwanBardolia Actually its working in my example, I guess its working fine now, else try to replicate in the stackblitz provided