# jQuery image url after redirect

Tags: jquery

I have a script like this:

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', images[i]).load(function() {
      alert(this.src); // old url
})
```

Sometimes the server will throw a `301 Moved Permanently` or `302 Moved Temporarily` HTTP code, and the actual image loaded will differ. How can I:

- detect if a redirection happened
- find out the new url - `this.src` doesn't take the redirect into account
- <strike>possibly
  prevent the new url from being loaded</strike>

?

[edit]
As per [How to prevent ajax requests to follow redirects using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238727/how-to-prevent-ajax-requests-to-follow-redirects-using-jquery), the last one is not possible. How can I find out the new URL?

Comment: In which situation do you get a redirect? What does "sometimes" mean? Why don't you want to follow the redirect?

Comment: @LutzHorn Irrelevant magic behind the project, can't work around that

Comment: OK, but why don't you want to follow the redirect?

Comment: @LutzHorn The redirect always contains an error message, no need for it to be loaded.

Comment: A redirect is not an error, it is a redirect. It contains a `Location` header which IMO the client should follow.

Comment: @LutzHorn The page the `Location` points to is always an image with the text "An error occured". Hence there is no need to load it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the status using an AJAX request, something like this:

```
var img =  new Image();
$(img).load(
'someimage.png', 
function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        $('#img').attr('src','someimage.png')
    } else {
        //do something with xhr.status
    }
});
```

Comment: This always returns 200, the 301/302 codes are transparent