# Need to access a different domain url

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I need to load page from this url: https://medalist-a805c.web.app/HeardSuggest_Medalist.html which actually loads a page from a express server. I'm able to use cors, the express middleware. But the problem is, even though i need to load this url: https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com eventually.

The weird problem i'm facing is it always returns the homepage rather than the url i am trying to get which is: https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com

Any help will be highly appreciated. Many Thanks.

This is for a expressjs server.

This is my frotend calling code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: _url,
        data: { uname: "embed", orgin: _origin },
        // dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'mode': 'no-cors',
            // "X-TOKEN": 'xxxxx',
            // 'x-Trigger': 'CORS',
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with',
            // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            // 'Authorization': 'Bearer fadsfasf asdfasdf'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("data: ", data);
            $("body").html(data);
        }
    });
```

And in backend i'm using `app.use(cors())`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your URL](https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com) is first returning a 302 redirect to the home page and then the `$.ajax()` system (actually the XMLHttpRequest system underneath it) is following that redirect automatically.

You can see a discussion of that topic here:

[How to prevent ajax requests to follow redirects using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238727/how-to-prevent-ajax-requests-to-follow-redirects-using-jquery)

In newer browsers, you can use the `fetch()` interface instead and it contains a [`redirect` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) that allows you to tell it not to follow redirects.

FYI, it's unclear what you're really trying to accomplish here.  There is no "page" to retrieve from [this URL](https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com).  That returns a 302 status and a few headers, no page.

---

In case this isn't clear to you, [your long url](https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com) returns this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 17:04:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 23
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.14.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: _csrf=j6JfsEb_JbmSJlvHDoyhgatS; Path=/
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A8C1PVNBcm5395dwmPJ4Xbl7BNASxPH4W.WFZ6uz3NklxaObnWvZaZXI%2BoH5VdM9dnOi2VCTw3J%2BI; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 15 Oct 2029 17:04:05 GMT; HttpOnly
Surrogate-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Location: /
Vary: Accept
```

This content was retrieved with `curl -l -v yourlongurl`.

Comment: could you give an example of fetch interface with redirect option plz?

Comment: @RezoanulAlamRiad - The redirect option is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).  It's trivial to use.  What problem are you really trying to solve here?  There's no content (other than headers) in the redirect response so I can't tell what problem you're really trying to solve here.

Comment: it should load the contents of that link. the content should be this: https://www.alwaysheard.com/test.html

Comment: @RezoanulAlamRiad - What exact URL are you trying to load with `$.ajax()`?  Because `https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com` does not load or redirect to `https://www.alwaysheard.com/test.html`.  It returns a 302 response with a location header of `/`.

Comment: this url: https://www.alwaysheard.com/test.html loads the desired content. and it is actually calling this url: https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com under the hood. Now i need to load those content from a different origin/domain. Is it understable now?

Comment: @RezoanulAlamRiad - I'm totally confused about what your question is.  Please add a step by step process to your question for what you expect to happen or what you're actually trying to do.  I tried to help based on my limited understanding of your question.  If this isn't what you wanted, then I can't help any more unless you clarify your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201110/discussion-between-rezoanul-alam-riad-and-jfriend00).

Comment: Ok, simply I need to load this url: https://www.alwaysheard.com/embed/Medalist/brand/$2a$10$Z9ib22YZyRWWZz/Vlzju3u9eZCZM.a8oUYorNPsKGzLPKu6vM696K?uname=embed&orgin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alwaysheard.com from a different domain. which is this: https://medalist-a805c.web.app/HeardSuggest_Medalist.html

Comment: @RezoanulAlamRiad - All that URL returns is a set of headers.  I added the actual response to the end of my question so you can see what it is.  I'm still confused about what you want.

Comment: i was able to sort out the problem with your answer. i got the clue. thanks a lot!