# 301 redirect on AJAX -- redirected?

Tags: ajax, redirect

I have an AJAX call to a server endpoint that does a 301 redirect to the same page, but with a trailing slash.

Does the browser follow redirects when called with AJAX or does it ignore them? In my case it doesn't follow them, but I figured it might be something from the server config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jquery you could look at the questions below to implement it. By default jQuery (and most libraries with Ajax) **don't follow** redirects by default:

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

[How to prevent ajax requests to follow redirects using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238727/how-to-prevent-ajax-requests-to-follow-redirects-using-jquery)

[handle jquery ajax redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804928/handle-jquery-ajax-redirect)

Comment: OK so jQuery doesn't follow redirects, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Um, no. XHR will transparently follow redirects.

Comment: Not in all cases. I've got a 301 redirect setup and FF doesn't follow them. Chrome does, however.

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question as asked. It talks about a library that isn't at all relevant to the actual question. Even then it's vague and relies way too heavily on links.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this answer is a little bit late but i had the same problem with 301 response on ajax request. The solution was quite simple:

apache rewrite rule is something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]\w+)/?$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,E=MODULE:$1]
```

Your XHR-Request url looks someting like this:

```
/this/is/a/canonical/url + '?param=1&param=2...'
```

It will lead to the 301 moved permanently if you dont use a direct file call (f.i. *.php) and rewrite to canonical URL (looks like a directory-path without f.i. *.php) instead.

To solve this problem just add a / to your XHR-Request-URL like this:

```
/this/is/a/canonical/url + '/' + '?param=1&param=2...'
```

Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and the suggestion about the trailing slash got me thinking ... I had a rewrite rule in my Web.Config to make everything lowercase and that's what was messing up my AJAX call.  I was POSTing to GetResults (which showed up as a 301) and my rewriter (for some unknown reason?) was changing it to a lower-cased getresults GET which resulted in a 404.

Hope this might help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

According to jQuery's API doc (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), `async:false` (aka. sync mode) does not support cross-domain and `dataType: "jsonp"` requests.

Comment: Sorry, but what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @EduardLuca I'm sorry, your redirection does not cross the domain.

Comment: I don't need to cross to another domain, the redirect happens on the same URL but with a trailing slash.