# Can a JavaScript function return itself?

Tags: javascript, function, self

Can I write a function that returns iteself?

I was reading some description on closures - [see Example 6](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html) - where a function was returning a function, so you could call `func()();` as valid JavaScript.

So I was wondering could a function return itself in such a way that you could chain it to itself indefinitely like this:

```
func(arg)(other_arg)()(blah);
```

Using `arguments` object, callee or caller?

Comment: Related question: [Javascript FAB framework on Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799238)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084872/an-object-that-returns-an-instance-of-itself

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791793/javascript-function-call-to-itself

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are 2-3 ways. One is, as you say, is to use `arguments.callee`. It might be the only way if you're dealing with an anonymous function that's not stored assigned to a variable somewhere (that you know of):

```
(function() {
    return arguments.callee;
})()()()().... ;
```

The 2nd is to use the function's name

```
function namedFunc() {
    return namedFunc;
}
namedFunc()()()().... ;
```

And the last one is to use an anonymous function assigned to a variable, but you have to know the variable, so in that case I see no reason, why you can't just give the function a name, and use the method above

```
var storedFunc = function() {
    return storedFunc;
};
storedFunc()()()().... ;
```

They're all functionally identical, but `callee` is the simplest.

Edit: And I agree with SLaks; I can't recommend it either

Comment: Worth noting that `arguments.callee` throws an error in ES5 Strict http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Comment: @abbotto Method 3 works fine for me, but yes method 2 is the "right" way to do it. As for deprecation, note that this answer is 5 years old

Comment: @Flambino, you are correct.

Method 1: Should generally be avoided altogether because arguments.callee has been deprecated. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Method 2: This is the best way to do a recursive function call in JS, because the function isn't anonymous and it's name will show up in stack traces.

Comment: @Flambino @MarkFox @abbotto can combine methods 1 and 2 to eliminate callee usage `(function X() {return X;})()()()().... ;` thereby aleviating deprecation issue. The function name also appears in stack traces.  It's concise, compliant and does not pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 13):

Yes.
Just `return arguments.callee;`

However, this is likely to result in very confusing code; I do not recommend it.

Comment: I would just name the function, instead using `arguments.callee` for two reasons: 1. Functions are generally optimized by implementations, if you don't use the `arguments` object, it won't be generally created (the execution context will be initialized faster) -of course, if the function uses `eval`, it usually can't be optimized-. 2. The `arguments` object had changes on ES5 strict mode, and the `arguments.callee` property has been disallowed  (again also for optimization and security concerns), so basically to write *future-proof* code, I would recommend to just name the function. :)

Comment: @CMS: Are you sure that `callee` is no longer allowed? I thought that was `caller`.

Comment: both are disallowed, and `caller` AFAIR was actually never part of the spec, but it was supported by many implementations, that's why on ES5, for strict functions, both `caller` and `callee` are assigned to a [thrower function](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.3), see the *Step 14* in [10.6  Arguments Object](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6)

Comment: Also, check this simple [benchmark test](http://jsperf.com/arguments-callee-vs-fn-name) to see how the `arguments` object creation affects performance. BTW, the `caller` property was really dangerous, it allowed to "break" closures in some implementations, for example in Spidermonkey some techniques [like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/cmsalvado/87C7c/) allow to *leak* privately scoped functions.

Answer (score 7):

You can do what you want as following:

```
// Do definition and execution at the same time.
var someFunction = (function someFunction() {

    // do stuff
    return someFunction
 })();

 console.log(someFunction)
```

[arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) is not supported in JavaScript strict mode.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 4):

Even sorter that all the above is:

```js
f=()=>f
```

Comment: How will you add any logic to the function?

Comment: Defining anything to a variable without const/let/var is a bad practice, and also it will not work in strict mode. @Sam you can add the logic to this arrow function using `{}` f.e. 
`const f = () => { console.log('test'); return f }`

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to achieve this doing the following:

```
let intArr = [];
function mul(x){
    if(!x){
        return intArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev * curr)
    }
    intArr.push(x);
    return mul;
}

console.log(mul(2)(4)(2)()); => outputs 16
```

Comment: reason for -1, this is not what was asked in the original post

Comment: @micnic OP asked for a function that returns itself. The above function returns itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SamuelEbert, yes this function returns itself, but also is bloated with functional which is useless for the context of the question and focuses on that additional functional. It's like I'd ask an example of usage the verb "to be" and I'd get as response "Hamlet" by Shakespeare without even pointing where is the example of the verb "to be" is in the text.

Comment: @micnic, Thank you for clarifying. I actually agree with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible just to return the argument the self invokable function like

```
console.log( (function(a) {  return a; })(1) ); // returns 1
```

Comment: why? he asked somthing that return function (itself) and i gave one.
was that confuse?