# Javascript: how to return own function?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a JavaScript function return itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959426/can-a-javascript-function-return-itself)

Consider the following javascript function:

```
var x = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    return x;
};

x('Hello')('World!');
```

This wil alert 'Hello' and 'World!'. Now I would like to rewrite the function without using a `var x` into something like:

```
(function(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
    return this;
})('Hello')('World');
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I return my own function from the function?

Comment: @Diodeus... well it depends... look at the answer of FishBasketGordo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`arguments.callee`](http://arguments.callee.info/2008/10/27/arguments-callee/) to return the current function:

```
(function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
  return arguments.callee;
})('Hello')('World');
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SC6jy/).

You can also name the function and reference it by it's name, like this:

```
(function showMessage(msg) {
  alert(msg);
  return showMessage;
})('Hello')('World');
```

See this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2zKM/).

EDIT: You asked what the best approach is. The answer is: it depends.

Since `arguments.callee` is deprecated in ECMAScript, that may be a reason to not use it. The second approach is more readable and complies with the standard in strict mode. However, `arguments.callee` does have some advantages:

- It works on anonymous functions
- You can rename the function without having to change the code inside
- You can reuse the code without having to adjust it for the name of the function it is inside.

Comment: Hm... doesn't compile. Needs '(' and ')' wrapped around the function. Thanks! :-)

Comment: What is the best approach, this one or FishBasketGordos?

Comment: @Kees, I've answered that in an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Is something like this acceptable?

```
(function doAlert(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    return doAlert;
}('Hello')('World'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/c33EG/

Comment: Nice... like it more than arguments.callee

Comment: +1 for the strict mode valid NFE.

Comment: What is the best approach this one or Peters?

Comment: @Kees: This approach will work when you decide to start using the `"use strict";` declarative.

Comment: @Kees: If you include `"use strict";` at the top of a function (or at the top of your entire code), then in newer browsers that support the "strict mode" rules, your code will be evaluated according to those rules. The rules are part of ECMAScript 5, and are designed to make you write better, safer code. Basically you'll get errors if you try to do some things that are considered poor practice. For example, if you try to assign to a variable without declaring it with `var` first, normally it implicitly creates a global variable. Strict mode will throw an error, letting you know of the mistake.

Comment: ...[run this code](http://jsfiddle.net/wvyFA/) in FF4+ or Chrome 13+, and you'll see that a simple `x = 10` now throws an error. This is a good thing, and it will help you write better code.

Answer (score 2):

Change `this` for `arguments.callee`